# Error in : corrupted double-linked list 0xb2808cf8 C++

Tags: c++, malloc

I get this error with my application.(On Windriver Linux)

```
 *** Error in `./BasicTimersTest': corrupted double-linked list: 0xb2808cf8 ***
```

As per backtrace, this is seen while allocating memory with new.

There are no double-linked lists in my code. I browsed about this issue and most of sites talking about similar issue but with **glibc detected** as prefix.

What is the difference between both and does the address printed in the error trace (0xb2808cf8) have any significance ?

Comment: Wind River is embedded stuff. I don't think they use glibc. That explains the different error message.

Comment: It is detected while allocating memory, but the actual corruption occurred earlier.  Does the "electric fence" allocator run correctly on Wind River?  Or valgrind?

Answer (score 1):

I saw this message where malloc data structures was corrupted, most likely you called free on wrong pointer, for example which doesn't point to beginning of allocated region, or which was already freed (double free), or somehow you writed into internal malloc structures, by writing outside of your array. It may happend a long before you called `new`, but you saw the problem only trying allocate new memory.